# How to get week number SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get Week number based on current date in SQL Server 2014?

Please note always year should starts from 1st February and year end will be 31st Jan.

Week Starts from Sunday to Saturday.

Comment: Do you mean you want the week with February 1 as week 1?

Comment: @jarlh yes please

Comment: I've seen a few varying definitions for "week", but this is a new one. Did you really mean February, rather than January? What week number should the weeks in January get, then? Are those going to be around 50?

Comment: @hvd I have updated my question. Please see

Comment: @user2331670 Thanks for that, then Gordon Linoff's answer looks right to me, with one note: it assumes weeks run from Sunday to Saturday. If that assumption is right for your week numbers, you can just accept his answer unless you find some other issue with it. If that assumption is wrong, please update your question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number of weeks since Feb 1 and then use that to calculate weeks:

```
select (case when month(getdate()) < 2
             then datediff(week,
                           datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 2, 1),
                           getdate()
                          )
             else datediff(week,
                           datefromparts(year(getdate()), 2, 1),
                           getdate()
                          )
         end)
```

Note:  `datefromparts()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012.  You can do similar things with strings and conversion to dates.

Comment: When I run this I get below error, "Msg 155, 
'weeks' is not a recognized datediff option."

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) < 2 THEN (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DATEADD(M,11,GETDATE())))/7 
            ELSE ((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())-31)/7)+1 
        END
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I ran your SQL query it returns Week 37. What will be the code if I want Previous week number (36) please?

Comment: In else part there is +1 , you can remove it but for 1st week it will return 0

Answer (score 0):

```
  declare @DATE_INSERT date='02-01-2014'
 select DATEPART(WK,@DATE_INSERT) - DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@DATE_INSERT),0)))) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you define week number, but you can try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART( wk, DATEADD('mm',-1,getdate()))
```

Comment: Number of weeks from Jan,1 to the day of the previous month may differ from number of weeks from Feb,1 to the day of next month.